# How can I get the initial value of a variabe in javascript after changing it on the DOM?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, selectors-api

I am trying to get the amount of ingredient required for a given portion in the input field.

When the amount changes on the dom, I am unable to acces the initial amount in the html. Because of that, I am unable to get the accurate amount for a give portion in the input field.

```js
function calcAmount() {
  let size = document.getElementById('portion').value;
  if (size < 1 || size > 5) {
    return;
  }
  let portions = document.querySelectorAll('.span');
  for (let i = 0; i < portions.length; i++) {
    let amount = parseInt(portions[i].innerText);
    let newAmount = amount * size;
    let portion = newAmount;
    portions[i].innerText = +portion;
    portions[i] = '';
  }
  document.getElementById('portion').value = ' ';
}
```

```html
<div class="container recipe-portion">
  <span>Zutaten für</span>
  <div class="portioning">
    <input id="portion" type="tex" placeholder="1 bis 5 eingeben" />
    <button onclick="calcAmount()" class="btn">Portionen</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container recipe-ingredients">
  <div class="ingredients">
    <p><span class="span">200</span>g Mehl</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ingredients">
    <p><span class="span">200</span>g Zucker</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ingredients">
    <p><span class="span">50</span>g Kakao</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do not keep values in innerHTML, use data-attribute or inputs tags

Comment: Or use a dictionary (`const ingredients = { mehl: 200, zucker: 200, kakao: 50 }`) and iterate over it, multiplying each value by `size`.

Comment: Thank you Andy. I used arrays and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use some sort of debugging system to see what is going on when your function runs. You need to visualize your program somehow. Here I used a simple console log command for all variables but there are better ways. And don't get values from html. Keep them in some sort of "source of truth", like an object or something else.

```js
function calcAmount() {
let size = document.getElementById('portion').value;
console.log("=========start===========")
console.log("size = " + size)

if (size < 1 || size > 5) {
  return;
}
let portions = document.querySelectorAll('.span');
console.log("portions = " + portions)
for (let i = 0; i < portions.length; i++) {
  let amount = parseInt(portions[i].innerText);
  console.log("amount = " + amount)
  let newAmount = amount * size;
  console.log("newAmount = " + newAmount)
  let portion = newAmount;
  console.log("portion = " + portion)
  portions[i].innerText = +portion;
  console.log("portions[i].innerText = " + portions[i].innerText)
  portions[i] = '';
  console.log("portions[i] = " + portions[i])
 

}
document.getElementById('portion').value = ' ';
console.log("('portion').value =" + document.getElementById('portion').value)
console.log("=========end===========")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped. I kept the values in an array and made reference to the values in the array for every new calculation and it worked as i expected. Thank you.